# Maximizing multiple functions using FindRoot with simulated values

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve for four variables (th1, tl1,th2,tl2) and simulate them for different values of a number of specific parameters. In this question I am focusing on a single parameter. a1. I first have to solve for a variable nh1 as a function of the t variables and the parameter a1 using FindRoot and Numericq?. I then define two new functions with these simulated values W1s and W2s and I want to maximize them with respect to the t variables. I use FindRoot to solve the first-order conditions and then define the variables as functions of a1.  Plots of Ws1 and Ws2 with the simulated values of nh1 suggest that there is an interior, real solution. But the numbers I am getting seem way off and the code takes a very long time to run.  Is there a better way to set up this solution procedure?  Below is the code.

````
In[4477]:= ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Free Parameters*)
nh = 100;
nl = 200;
a = .3;
b = .4;
ah = 1;
al = 1;
a2 = 1;
s = 1.1;
gamma = .1;
p = 1;
(*Define key functions*)

Y1 = a1 (b (ah nh1)^((s - 1)/s) + (1 - 
         b) (al nl1)^((s - 1)/s))^(s/(s - 1));
Y2 = a2 (b (ah nh2)^((s - 1)/s) + (1 - 
         b) (al nl2)^((s - 1)/s))^(s/(s - 1));
wh1 = D[Y1, nh1];
wl1 = D[Y1, nl1];
wh2 = D[Y2, nh2];
wl2 = D[Y2, nl2];
nl1 = (((1 - tl1) (1 - th2))^
      s nh1 nl)/(((1 - tl1) (1 - th2))^s nh1 + ((1 - tl2) (1 - th1))^
       s (nh - nh1));
nl2 = nl - nl1;
nh2 = nh - nh1;
q1 = (a Y1)^(1/(1 + p));
q2 = (a Y2)^(1/(1 + p));
g1 = (th1 wh1 nh1 + tl1 wl1 nl1)/(q1^a);
g2 = (th2 wh2 nh2 + tl2 wl2 nl2)/(q2^a);
Vh1[nh1_, a1_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, 
   tl2_] = (g1)^gamma (1 - th1) wh1/(q1^a);
Vl1[nh1_, a1_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, 
   tl2_] = (g1)^gamma (1 - tl1) wl1/(q1^a);
Vh2[nh1_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, tl2_] = (g2)^gamma (1 - th2) wh2/(q2^a);
Vl2[nh1_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, tl2_] = (g2)^gamma (1 - tl2) wl2/(q2^a);

(*Solve for variable nh1 as function of t's and parameter a1*)

nh1s[a1_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_?NumericQ] := 
  nh1 /. FindRoot[
    Vh1[nh1, a1, th1, tl1, th2, tl2] - Vh2[nh1, th1, tl1, th2, tl2] ==
      0, {nh1, 50}];

(*Define remaining variables with simulated values of nh1*)

nl1s[a1_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, 
   tl2_] = (((1 - tl1) (1 - th2))^s nh1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, 
      tl2] nl)/(((1 - tl1) (1 - th2))^s nh1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, 
       tl2] + ((1 - tl2) (1 - th1))^
       s (nh - nh1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2]));
nh2s[a1_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = 
  nh - nh1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2];
nl2s[a1_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = 
  nl - nl1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2];
(*Define two new functions with simulated variables*)

W1s[a1_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = 
  Vl1[nh1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], a1, th1, tl1, th2, tl2] nl1s[a1, 
    th1, th2, tl1, tl2];
W2s[a1_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = 
  Vl2[nh2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th1, tl1, th2, tl2] nl2s[a1, th1, 
    th2, tl1, tl2];
(*Solve for t's as the solution to a set of first-order conditions*)

th1s[a1_?NumericQ] := 
  th1 /. FindRoot[{D[W1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th1] == 0, 
     D[W1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], tl1] == 0, 
     D[W2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th2] == 0, 
     D[W2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], tl2] == 
      0}, {{th1, .2}, {tl1, .1}, {th2, .2}, {tl2, .1}}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3 0];
tl1s[a1_?NumericQ] := 
  tl1 /. FindRoot[{D[W1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th1] == 0, 
     D[W1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], tl1] == 0, 
     D[W2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th2] == 0, 
     D[W2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], tl2] == 
      0}, {{th1, .2}, {tl1, .1}, {th2, .2}, {tl2, .1}}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3];
th2s[a1_?NumericQ] := 
  th2 /. FindRoot[{D[W1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th1] == 0, 
     D[W1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], tl1] == 0, 
     D[W2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th2] == 0, 
     D[W2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], tl2] == 
      0}, {{th1, .2}, {tl1, .1}, {th2, .2}, {tl2, .1}}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3];
tl2s[a1_?NumericQ] := 
  tl2 /. FindRoot[{D[W1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th1] == 0, 
     D[W1s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], tl1] == 0, 
     D[W2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], th2] == 0, 
     D[W2s[a1, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], tl2] == 
      0}, {{th1, .2}, {tl1, .1}, {th2, .2}, {tl2, .1}}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3];
(*What should be a symmetric solution is asymmetric and doesn't \
generate a real solution and takes a very long time. Graphs with the \
simulations suggest that there is a real and positive interior \
maximum*)

In[4515]:= th1s[1]
tl1s[1]
th2s[1]
tl2s[1]

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function ({<<8>>+(<<19>> <<4>> (<<1>>))/((<<1>>)^<<19>> <<2>> <<1>>)==0,<<1>>==0,<<1>>,-((0.731857 (200-(200 <<1>><<1>>nh1s[1,th1,th2,tl1,tl2])/Plus[<<2>>]) (<<1>>+<<1>>)^<<18>> ((Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<4>>])/Power[<<1>>]^0.15)^0.1)/((200-200 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>])^0.909091 ((<<1>>)^<<19>>)^0.15))+<<6>>+(0.0731857 <<3>> (-(<<1>>/<<1>>)+<<1>>))/((200-<<1>>)^<<19>> <<1>>^<<5>> (<<1>>/<<1>>)^0.9)==0}) is less than WorkingPrecision (10.`).

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::cvmit will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[4515]= 0.2012704301 - 1.011584167*10^-15 I

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function ({<<8>>+(<<19>> <<4>> (<<1>>))/((<<1>>)^<<19>> <<2>> <<1>>)==0,<<1>>==0,<<1>>,-((0.731857 (200-(200 <<1>><<1>>nh1s[1,th1,th2,tl1,tl2])/Plus[<<2>>]) (<<1>>+<<1>>)^<<18>> ((Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<4>>])/Power[<<1>>]^0.15)^0.1)/((200-200 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>])^0.909091 ((<<1>>)^<<19>>)^0.15))+<<6>>+(0.0731857 <<3>> (-(<<1>>/<<1>>)+<<1>>))/((200-<<1>>)^<<19>> <<1>>^<<5>> (<<1>>/<<1>>)^0.9)==0}) is less than WorkingPrecision (10.`).

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::cvmit will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[4516]= 0.09999998537 + 1.415751586*10^-15 I

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function ({<<8>>+(<<19>> <<4>> (<<1>>))/((<<1>>)^<<19>> <<2>> <<1>>)==0,<<1>>==0,<<1>>,-((0.731857 (200-(200 <<1>><<1>>nh1s[1,th1,th2,tl1,tl2])/Plus[<<2>>]) (<<1>>+<<1>>)^<<18>> ((Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<4>>])/Power[<<1>>]^0.15)^0.1)/((200-200 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>])^0.909091 ((<<1>>)^<<19>>)^0.15))+<<6>>+(0.0731857 <<3>> (-(<<1>>/<<1>>)+<<1>>))/((200-<<1>>)^<<19>> <<1>>^<<5>> (<<1>>/<<1>>)^0.9)==0}) is less than WorkingPrecision (10.`).

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::cvmit will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[4517]= 0.2000000000

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function ({<<8>>+(<<19>> <<4>> (<<1>>))/((<<1>>)^<<19>> <<2>> <<1>>)==0,<<1>>==0,<<1>>,-((0.731857 (200-(200 <<1>><<1>>nh1s[1,th1,th2,tl1,tl2])/Plus[<<2>>]) (<<1>>+<<1>>)^<<18>> ((Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<4>>])/Power[<<1>>]^0.15)^0.1)/((200-200 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>])^0.909091 ((<<1>>)^<<19>>)^0.15))+<<6>>+(0.0731857 <<3>> (-(<<1>>/<<1>>)+<<1>>))/((200-<<1>>)^<<19>> <<1>>^<<5>> (<<1>>/<<1>>)^0.9)==0}) is less than WorkingPrecision (10.`).

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

During evaluation of In[4515]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::cvmit will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[4518]= 0.1000000000
```
````

Comment: Have you verified that `nhls` works for a range of reasonable input values?  Also, why do you check that `tl2` is numeric, but not the other input variables?

Comment: Yes I did. Here U have tried the value of the function in four different ways. I tried all of the variables numerically not just tl2 and I still get inconsistent answers.  In[5987]:= nh1s[1, .1, .1, .1, .1]
nh1s[1.05, .1, .1, .1, .1]
nh1s[1.05, .1, .15, .1, .1]
nh1s[1.05, .1, .1, .1, .15]

Out[5987]= 50.

Out[5988]= 66.8593

Out[5989]= 69.1549

Out[5990]= 68.8156